# Pandas Pivot Dates

Tags: pandas, date, pivot

I have the following df:

```
user_id    step    date
1         start    2018-04-17 15:27:07
1         step1    2018-04-17 15:28:07
1         end      2018-04-17 15:29:07
2         start    2018-05-17 15:28:07
2         step1    2018-05-17 15:29:07
2         end      2018-05-17 15:30:07
```

and I need to transform it to the following table:

```
user_id   start                  end                   time (end-start)
1         2018-04-17 15:27:07    2018-04-17 15:29:07   2
2         2018-05-17 15:28:07    2018-05-17 15:30:07   2
```

I am stuck on this one, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot and find timedelta

```
new_df = df.pivot('user_id', 'step', 'date').drop('step1', 1).reset_index()
new_df.columns.name = None
new_df['time (end-start)'] = (new_df['end'] - new_df['start']).astype('timedelta64[m]')


    user_id end                 start               time (end-start)
0   1       2018-04-17 15:29:07 2018-04-17 15:27:07 2.0
1   2       2018-05-17 15:30:07 2018-05-17 15:28:07 2.0
```

Edit: For dataframe with duplicate entries, like this:

```
    user_id step    date
0   1   start   2018-04-17 15:27:07
1   1   step1   2018-04-17 15:28:07
2   1   end     2018-04-17 15:29:07
3   1   end     2018-04-17 15:32:07
4   2   start   2018-05-17 15:26:07
5   2   start   2018-05-17 15:28:07
6   2   step1   2018-05-17 15:29:07
7   2   end     2018-05-17 15:30:07

new_df = df.pivot_table(index = 'user_id', columns = 'step', values = 'date', aggfunc = 'first').drop('step1', 1).reset_index() 

new_df.columns.name = None

new_df['time (end-start)'] = (new_df['end'] - new_df['start']).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

You get

```
    user_id end                 start               time (end-start)
0   1       2018-04-17 15:29:07 2018-04-17 15:27:07 2.0
1   2       2018-05-17 15:30:07 2018-05-17 15:26:07 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it did not work. I have a big set and there are duplicate values, for example user 1 could have end dates twice and we would want to use the earliest for both start and end.

Comment: If you have duplicated values, you need to use pivot_table instead of pivot with an appropriate aggfunc.